# How to reload javascript but not page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with a slider. When I load the first time my Web page, it shows a slider with some images. I have some links to change the images to show, so when I click, I want to display as a slider the other ones. The problem is that when I click on the new link, it doesn't use the jquery function to format the slider.

Here I paste some code so you can figure out:

```
<div class="contenidor_escaparates_2011">
    <div id="contenidor_slider" class="containerGaleria">
        <ul id="slideshow">
              <li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img1.jpg" alt="Dormitorio azul turquesa." /></li>
              <li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img2.jpg" alt="Escaparate Agosto 2011." /></li>
              <li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img3.jpg" alt="Escaparate Enero 2011." /></li>
</ul> </div></div>
```

And then the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var timeout, manualMode = false,

            $slideshow = $('#slideshow'),
    $items = $slideshow.find('li').hide(),
    total = $items.length,
    getItem = function($item, trav) {
        var $returnItem = $item[trav]();
        return $returnItem.length ?
            $returnItem :
            $items[(trav == 'next') ? 'first' : 'last']();
    },

    showItem = function($currentItem, $itemToShow) {
        var $itemToShow =
            $itemToShow || getItem($currentItem,'next');

        $currentItem.fadeOut(300, function() {
            $itemToShow.fadeIn(300, fadeCallback);
        });
    },

    fadeCallback = function() {
        if (manualMode) { return; }

        var $this = $(this),
            $next = getItem($this, 'next'),
            num = $this.prevAll().length + 1;


        // set the timeout for showing
        // the next item in 5 seconds
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            showItem($this, $next);
        }, 3000);
    },

    handleBtnClick = function(e) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);

        manualMode = true;

        var $currentItem = $items.filter(':visible'),
            $itemToShow = getItem($currentItem, e.data.direction);

        showItem($currentItem, $itemToShow);
    };

    $items.eq(0).fadeIn(500, fadeCallback);

});
```

This works perfect for the first time I load the page, but when I change the content with this:

```
<script type="text/>
$('#nuestra_tienda_show').click(function()
    {
     $('.containerGaleria').html('');
     $('<ul id="slideshow"><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img1.jpg" alt="Dormitorio azul turquesa." /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img2.jpg" alt="Escaparate Agosto 2011." /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img3.jpg" alt="Escaparate Enero 2011." /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img4.jpg" alt="Escaparate Junio 2011." /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img5.jpg" alt="" /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img6.jpg" alt="" /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img7.jpg" alt="" /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img8.jpg" alt="" /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img9.jpg" alt="" /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img10.jpg" alt="" /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img11.jpg" alt="" /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img12.jpg" alt="" /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img13.jpg" alt="" /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img14.jpg" alt="" /></li></ul> ')
         .prependTo('.containerGaleria');
         $('#galeria_seleccionada').html('Nuestra tienda 2011');
         location.reload();
         });
</script>
```

So basically, what I do is, after an onclick() event on some link, I change the html content of a div, but obviously, it doesn't use the jquery, as it wasn't loaded at first. Any idea on how to solve this?

If I use location.reload(); it shows the first items I had inside, so it doesn't work for me...

EDIT:
Wait, I edit the jsFiddle...

Comment: Why you don't wrap your gallery code in a function and call it on document ready. Then, if you need to change the elements, change them and call function again?

Comment: We don't have the html for the rest of the subject. Please post the html code for your links/buttons

Comment: You can't remove javascript that has already executed, however, you can re-execute javascript by storing it in a function and running the function multiple times as needed.

Comment: <script type="text/> should be <script type="text/javascript">
Can you create a js fiddle or update this one: http://jsfiddle.net/6ZvFW/
And post the new link in your question

Comment: Rather than reloading the javascript, you need another function that will swap the images on the page. I'm going through your code now and writing an example, will post in a few minutes.

Comment: UPDATED the jsFiddle. But didn't add images... Dunno how! But if you click on the second link on the left, you see that images on the central div should change .... but as I make a location.reload() it uses same images than the first time. What I need is that the second link puts the images on the slider. But if I erase the location.reload(), images don't show as a slider...

Comment: So basically what I want is change the slider images and use the .js that does that without reloading the page... Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an init method for your slideshow and recall that when you need to.

I want to gag seeing how this js is set up so I will ignore it and post how I would have handled it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    slideshow.init();

    $('#nuestra_tienda_show').on('click', function()
    {
        $('.containerGaleria').html('');
        $('<ul id="slideshow"><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img1.jpg" alt="Dormitorio azul turquesa." /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img2.jpg" alt="Escaparate Agosto 2011." /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img3.jpg" alt="Escaparate Enero 2011." /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img4.jpg" alt="Escaparate Junio 2011." /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img5.jpg" alt="" /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img6.jpg" alt="" /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img7.jpg" alt="" /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img8.jpg" alt="" /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img9.jpg" alt="" /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img10.jpg" alt="" /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img11.jpg" alt="" /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img12.jpg" alt="" /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img13.jpg" alt="" /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img14.jpg" alt="" /></li></ul> ')
        .prependTo('.containerGaleria');
        $('#galeria_seleccionada').html('Nuestra tienda 2011');
        slideshow.init();
    });
});

var slideshow = {
    timeout: null,
    manualMode: false,
    total: 0,
    init: function(){
        clearTimeout(this.timeout);
        var items = $('#slideshow').find('li').hide();
        this.total = items.length;
        items.eq(0).fadeIn(500, this.fadeCallback);
    },
    getItem: function(item, trav) {
        var returnItem = item[trav]();
        return returnItem.length ?
            returnItem :
            items[(trav == 'next') ? 'first' : 'last']();
    },
    showItem: function(currentItem, itemToShow) {
        var itemToShow =
            itemToShow || this.getItem(currentItem,'next');

        currentItem.fadeOut(300, function() {
            itemToShow.fadeIn(300, this.fadeCallback);
        });
    },
    fadeCallback: function() {
        if (manualMode) { return; }

        var $this = $(this),
            next = getItem($this, 'next'),
            num = $this.prevAll().length + 1;

        // set the timeout for showing
        // the next item in 5 seconds
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            this.showItem($this, next);
        }, 3000);
    },
    handleBtnClick: function(e) {
        clearTimeout(this.timeout);

        this.manualMode = true;

        var currentItem = items.filter(':visible'),
            itemToShow = this.getItem(currentItem, e.data.direction);

        this.showItem(currentItem, itemToShow);
    },
    handleBtnClick: function(e) {
        clearTimeout(this.timeout);

        this.manualMode = true;

        var currentItem = items.filter(':visible'),
            itemToShow = this.getItem(currentItem, e.data.direction);

        this.showItem(currentItem, itemToShow);
    };
};
```

Then you would just call `slideshow.init()` when you want to re-evaluate the slideshow content.

I didn't thoroughly audit this but the general idea is to turn this massive chain of vars into a single js object and contain the whole thing.

I cannot understand why you would write the contents of the slideshow like this in the click function. You're wiping the html of the container, creating the elements, then prepending them to the container and rewriting the title id with the same string over and over. Why not just set the html of the slideshow to the new images?

```
$('#slideshow').html('<li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img1.jpg" alt="Dormitorio azul turquesa." /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img2.jpg" alt="Escaparate Agosto 2011." /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img3.jpg" alt="Escaparate Enero 2011." /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img4.jpg" alt="Escaparate Junio 2011." /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img5.jpg" alt="" /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img6.jpg" alt="" /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img7.jpg" alt="" /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img8.jpg" alt="" /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img9.jpg" alt="" /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img10.jpg" alt="" /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img11.jpg" alt="" /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img12.jpg" alt="" /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img13.jpg" alt="" /></li><li><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img14.jpg" alt="" /></li>');
```

Comment: Although I think your solution is swell and everything, I don't see why Sonhja's code would make you gag. There are different styles of coding and there's space for everyone. Maybe he's still learning, maybe he doesn't care for the organization an object provides... Given such a simple task, what exactly are the benefits of organizing everything so neatly? It might just be your personal taste, you know?

Comment: It's a good solution, but you changed it so much, I can't understand it and actually the slider doesn't work... It's almost done! But it doesn't slide... Changes content perfectly, but doesn't slide... >_<

@BeetleTheNeato Yes... so newby... but woman!!

Comment: I work for a firm and we maintain certain habits to avoid confusion when code is handled by others. You can have your own style, go ahead. But if you apply for a job here and I see that code you better have a very impressive portfolio or I will end up believing the curve for adjustment may be too high to justify the expense. Nothing personal, just a reality. Anyhow, it can't hurt to be warned about this kind of thing. I didn't know when I started, but it might have been nice.

Comment: @sonhja - It may not work as is. As I said I didn't audit it fully. But getting it to work would be minimally challenging. Anyhow, even if it doesn't work out of the box, the general idea is the same: make a function to handle checking the slideshow length and populating the content. then call that function in the click listener you have set up AS WELL AS when page loads.

Comment: @Kai Qing if I only change the images, it doesn't work. I'm gonna try deeply your first solution, but still doesn't work... But thanks.

Comment: Well don't go nuts on it. If I have time today I will setup a fiddle and make it work. It shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: I think it's not, but can't figure out right now why it doesn't slide... Too many hours programming right now... :( Thanks, @Kai Qing ..., that would be appreciated

Comment: Done! A mixture between your idea and mine... Thanks a lot, @Kai Qing !!